# Como gerar um arquivo .apk no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Se já for gerado em qual pasta ele está localizado?

Comment: `Build > Generate Signed APK` para gerar o APK final.

Comment: muito obrigado!!

Comment: @LucasNunes http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2333/por-que-muitas-pessoas-respondem-nos-coment%C3%A1rios-em-vez-de-criar-uma-resposta

Comment: @Victor Eu fui #5, mas respondi direitinho agora.

Answer (score 29):

Depende de qual apk você se refere. Toda vez que você compila seu projeto no Android Studio e roda ele você está gerando um apk. A diferença está na configuração da compilação.

Quando você só compila para teste (debug), você gera um apk de desenvolvimento, que geralmente fica em:

```
SEU_PROJETO\app\build\outputs\apk
```

Com um nome do tipo:

```
app-debug.apk
```

Esse apk só deve ser utilizado para testes e desenvolvimento. Você **não** entrega essa versão para o usuário.

---

Para versão final, de release, você deve fazer uma assinatura digital no apk, para então enviar para a store. Para isso, vá em `Build > Generate Signed APK`, conforme a imagem:

[image: Demonstração do Menu]

Então, você deve assinar o apk preenchendo as informações na janela que vai surgir:

[image: Janela de Assinatura]

Essa chave (senha e arquivo), deve ser **bem guardada**, pois você pode precisar dela para fazer atualizações no apk. Se perder essa chave, o Google não vai autorizar a atualização e não tem o que fazer (a não ser cadastrar outro app).

Finalmente, depois dessa janela o Android Studio vai compilar o apk assinado e vai abrir já na pasta onde ele está. Esse você pode enviar para a store.

Comment: Eu posso preencher esses campos com qualquer valor?

Comment: Como eu instalo esse apk em um android qualquer? Não consegui...

Comment: @debeka Pesquise sobre `adb install PATH_DO_APK`